# pip install -r requirements.txt installs django instead of upgading it

Tags: django, installation, virtualenv, pip

I created requirements.txt file using `pip freeze --local`

Now, when I do: `pip install -r requirements.txt`

it installs new django over a top of an old version.
Then, I get the message:

```
========
WARNING!
========

You have just installed Django over top of an existing
installation, without removing it first. Because of this,
your install may now include extraneous files from a
previous version that have since been removed from
Django. This is known to cause a variety of problems. You
should manually remove the

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django

directory and re-install Django.
```

I want it to do an upgrade, if I have an old version installed. How can I manage that?

Answer (score 1):

From virtualenv tag I assume you are using virtualenv and it was created with --system-site-packages option. If that's true it is the reason why you see the warning. You have global django installation in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django and local inside virtualenv.

If I remember correctly you can ignore global packages by adding empty no-global-site-packages.txt file to lib directory inside your virtualenv.

Alternatively you can create new virtualenv with default settings (which means --no-site-packages option).

Comment: I agree with the later, create a new virtualenv. It doesn't seem to be the problem but also make sure to NEVER use sudo with virtualenv - not when creating the venv and not when doing pip install.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the above works for me. I created virtualenv with no options, so _no-global-site-packages.txt_ file exists in _lib/pythonX.Y/_ directory. However, after sourcing my virtualenv _activate_ file and unsetting PYTHONPATH, I still get a warning about old Django version while doing `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Comment: Have you tried checking your path from interpreter? I mean: import sys, sys.path

Answer (score -2):

this should do the trick:

```
pip install --upgrade django
```

Comment: I want to use _requirements.txt_ file created by `pip freeze` for automatic environment installation.